Issue with monitor resolution when using a KVM switch
I have a desktop machine with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and a Dell P2715Q monitor. When I plug the monitor directly to the computer, I can use up to the maximum resolution of 3840 x 2160. However, when I plug the monitor to the computer through a Kceve 4K KVM switch, I can only get up to 1920 x 1080 resolution. I have tried plugging in a Mac through the KVM switch to the same monitor, which allowed me to use the maximum resolution (3840 x 2160), and also a Debian machine where the resolution was also limited to 1920 x 1080 (when I plug in the Debian machine directly to the monitor, I can again use resolution up to 3840 x 2160). Is there anything that I need to change in the Ubuntu settings so that I can use higher resolution through the KVM switch? All of this is happening at 60Hz, which is also the supported refresh rate of the KVM switch.

If your details are correct; I suggest applying security fixes & other upgrades asap if your box is used online. This link ( https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/ ) shows the ISO release date of 22.04.4, but installed systems upgraded to that before the ISO release date, so your details (if accurate) show you not applied security & other fixes in some time.

Got it, the machine is used locally in fact but I will upgrade asap. I do not believe this is what is causing the monitor issues, though, do you?

Sounds like the monitor EDID settings (what resolutions/refresh rates it supports) are not getting to Ubuntu when it's connected via the KVM. You can run xrandr to see what resolutions are listed when it's directly connected vs when it's connected to the KVM.
If you are using X11/Xorg and NOT Wayland then you can add/force certain resolutions using xrandr see here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions
Alternatively I have read about downloading EDID data or creating custom EDID files/config and then doing settings in xorg.conf to allow missing resolutions.
However, I don't know how you would do either using Wayland. I am sure you can, I just don't know...
